# Terraform - Flatten - generate new index

Tags: terraform

Is there any way to generate an index for a string list?

Ideally integrated with using the flatten function?

eg from example here https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten it would also generate a new key for me

```
locals {
  network_subnets = flatten([
    for network_key, network in var.networks : [
      for subnet_key, subnet in network.subnets : {
        network_key = network_key
        subnet_key  = subnet_key
        network_id  = aws_vpc.example[network_key].id
        cidr_block  = subnet.cidr_block
        new_key     = 
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting this new key to be ?

Comment: What exactly is `var.networks`?

Comment: var.networks is just from the example nothing special about it. I would like it to create a new index 0,1,2,3 etc until all flattened entries have a new index

Comment: You have to provide complete example of an expected outcome.

Comment: The hascorp example uses concat of the keys of the 2 loops in the flatten.  So if the are 2 networks and 2 subnets. That would give index for flattend output  as 0.0, 0.1  1.0. 1.1. Ideally I would want to be able to set this as typical tf index  0,1,2,3 instead. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of this `flatten` operation will be a flat list, and so the indices of the elements of that list will be just consecutive integers as usual for list indices.

If you intend to use this with `for_each` and therefore need the result to be a mapping with the index as one of the object attributes instead, you can project the list into a mapping as a separate step:

```
locals {
  network_subnets_list = flatten([
    for network_key, network in var.networks : [
      for subnet_key, subnet in network.subnets : {
        network_key = network_key
        subnet_key  = subnet_key
        network_id  = aws_vpc.example[network_key].id
        cidr_block  = subnet.cidr_block
      }
    ]
  ])
  network_subnets_map = tomap({
    for i, s in local.network_subnets_list :
    "${s.network_key}:${s.subnet_key}" => merge(
      s,
      { new_key = i },
    )
  })
}
```

Although I've showed it as a local value here, you could alternatively just inline the `network_subnets_map` expression directly into the `for_each` argument, which would then make this similar to the example you were referring to in the `flatten` documentation:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "example" {
  # local.network_subnets is a list, so we must now project it into a map
  # where each key is unique. We'll combine the network and subnet keys to
  # produce a single unique key per instance.
  for_each = {
    for i, s in local.network_subnets_list :
    "${s.network_key}:${s.subnet_key}" => merge(
      s,
      { new_key = i },
    )
  }

  # ...

}
```

This is similar to the one from the documentation but with two differences:

- The `for` expression uses `i, s` instead of just `subnet`, where `i` is the current index and `s` is the current subnet object. (You can use `subnet` instead of `s` if you find that more readable.)
- Rather than just assigning the subnet object directly to the value of each map element, I used [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) to insert the additional `new_key` attribute, setting it to `i`. That means it would be available as `each.value.new_key` when you are defining other arguments inside the resource block.

Comment: Excellent thanks, I just couldn't wrap my head around how to do it....